# Mapping Nullable type Code First

Tags: entity-framework, datetime, ef-code-first, mapping, nullable

I have my project run just fine using EF Code First. But now I need to add 1 more field into DB(e.g CreateDate of type DateTime) which can be null.

So, I wrote script to add 1 more field to DB(CreateDate (datetime) **null**), then I modified my model to include new field

```
public class Account()
{
...
public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

And below is the code to make this field option using FluentApi

```
Property(x => x.CreateDate).IsOptional();
```

The problem is when I tried to get any instance of Account, I got an error
When I modify the field as follow:

```
public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
```

then it works.

Can you guys please explain to me about this? Why doesn't my fluent api work or did I do something wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You already gave the solution in your question... :) You must declare the new property as:

```
public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
```

`DateTime?` is a [nullable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and means that `CreateDate` can be null.

This is necessary because when a record is brought from the database and its `CreateDate` is `NULL` the backing property on your model should accept null as a possible value. If you declare the property as just `DateTime CreateDate` the framework gives you the error to inform that it could not assign the `NULL` value to a property that doesn't accept `NULL`.

So you should have:

```
public class Account()
{
    ...

    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, so what is the fluentapi for?

Comment: The Fluent API statement `Property(x => x.CreateDate).IsOptional();
` will take care of creating a nullable CreateDate column on the DB side.

Answer (score 4):

Try based on this example:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext and fluent Api:

```
public class dbMvc1:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Student { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Property(x => x.Birthday).IsOptional();
    }
}
```

Comment: does not contain a definition for 'IsOptional'  -> FYI does not work for EntityFrameworkCore